# One of the more overlooked and commonly caused reason for FATAL EXCEPTION ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, oop, classnotfoundexception

So after getting this error I checked my classPaths, tried to run Android JUnit test, and was stuck for hours before I realized that the problem was staring right at me in the face:

One of the more overlooked causes for this error are because you had another activity listed as the main activity and then deleted that file on import, causing java to not find the original class, hence ClassNotFoundException. I explain the solution who face this particular problem in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the default activity for your app by going into the AndroidManifest.xml and getting these lines:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

And making sure they are in the activity tag of the activity you want to be the default one. Another thing you can do is replace the activity label

```
android:name="com.example.testdatabaseactivity.<deletedActivity>"
```

with

```
android:name="com.example.testdatabaseactivity.<newDefaultActivity>"
```

I felt REALLY good when my code finally ran on whichever platform I wanted it to run on and just wanted to share the knowledge! :)